# Qt 5 'SelectDataDialog' object has no attribute 'connect' error

Tags: python, qt5

I try to translate a Qt4 code to Qt5 and I get this error wiyh the code above : 'SelectDataDialog' object has no attribute 'connect'

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class SelectDataDialog(QDialog, ui_DataSelect.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SelectDataDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Connect up the buttons.
        self.connect(self.okButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), SLOT('accept()'))


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)`.